# RDD/Scala Get one column from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD[Log]` file with various fields (`username,content,date,bytes`) and I want to find different things for each field/column.

For example, I want to get the min/max and average bytes found in the RDD. When i do:

```
val q1 = cleanRdd.filter(x => x.bytes != 0)
```

I get the full lines of the RDD with bytes != 0. But how can I actually sum them, calculate the avg, find the min/max etc? How can I take only one column from my RDD and apply transformations on it?

EDIT: Prasad told me about changing the type to dataframe, he gave no instructions on how to do so though, and I cant find a solid answer on the site. Any help would be great.

EDIT: LOG class:

```
case class Log (username: String, date: String, status: Int, content: Int)
```

using a cleanRdd.take(5).foreach(println) gives something like this

```
Log(199.72.81.55 ,01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400,200,6245)
Log(unicomp6.unicomp.net ,01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400,200,3985)
Log(199.120.110.21 ,01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400,200,4085)
Log(burger.letters.com ,01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400,304,0)
Log(199.120.110.21 ,01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400,200,4179)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...  you have a lot of questions.

So... you have the following abstraction of a Log

```
case class Log (username: String, date: String, status: Int, content: Int, byte: Int)
```

Que - How can I take only one column from my RDD.

Ans - You have a `map` function with the RDD's. So for an `RDD[A]`, `map` takes a map/transform function of type `A => B` to transform it into a `RDD[B]`.

```
val logRdd: RDD[Log] = ...

val byteRdd = logRdd
  .filter(l => l.bytes != 0)
  .map(l => l.byte)
```

Que - how can I actually sum them ?

Ans - You can do it by using `reduce` / `fold` / `aggregate`.

```
val sum = byteRdd.reduce((acc, b) => acc + b)

val sum = byteRdd.fold(0)((acc, b) => acc + b)

val sum = byteRdd.aggregate(0)(
  (acc, b) => acc + b,
  (acc1, acc2) => acc1 + acc2
)
```

Note :: An important thing to notice here is that a sum of `Int` can grow bigger than what an `Int` can handle. So in most real life cases we should use at least a `Long` as our accumulator instead of an `Int`, which actually removes `reduce` and `fold` as options. And we will be left with an aggregate only.

```
val sum = byteRdd.aggregate(0l)(
  (acc, b) => acc + b,
  (acc1, acc2) => acc1 + acc2
)
```

Now if you have to calculate multiple things like min, max, avg then I will suggest that you calculate them in a single `aggregate` instead of multiple like this,

```
// (count, sum, min, max)
val accInit = (0, 0, Int.MaxValue, Int.MinValue)

val (count, sum, min, max) = byteRdd.aggregate(accInit)(
  { case ((count, sum, min, max), b) => 
      (count + 1, sum + b, Math.min(min, b), Math.max(max, b)) },
  { case ((count1, sum1, min1, max1), (count2, sum2, min2, max2)) => 
      (count1 + count2, sum1 + sum2, Math.min(min1, min2), Math.max(max1, max2)) }
})

val avg = sum.toDouble / count
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `DataFrame` API. You need to convert your RDD to a DataFrame and then you can use min, max, avg functions like below:

```
val rdd = cleanRdd.filter(x => x.bytes != 0)
val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, classOf[Log])
```

Assuming you wanted to operations on column `bytes` then

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(avg("bytes")).show
df.select(min("bytes")).show
df.select(max("bytes")).show
```

### Update:

Tried with the following in spark-shell. check the screenshots for the outcome...

```
case class Log (username: String, date: String, status: Int, content: Int)

val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(Log("199.72.81.55","01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400",200,6245), Log("unicomp6.unicomp.net","01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400",200,3985), Log("199.120.110.21","01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400",200,4085), Log("burger.letters.com","01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400",304,0), Log("199.120.110.21","01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400",200,4179)))

val rdd = inputRDD.filter(x => x.content != 0)

val df = rdd.toDF("username", "date", "status", "content")

df.printSchema

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(avg("content")).show
df.select(min("content")).show
df.select(max("content")).show
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do it without converting my RDD? Is it usual to convert the RDD to Dataframe for such actions?

Comment: also, how do I use the commands you gave me, i get an error "error: not found: value sparkSession"

Comment: use `SparkSession` instance to convert an RDD to DataFrame. In case if you are running this in `spark-shell` then instead of `sparkSession` use `spark`

Comment: WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
17/02/27 12:21:07 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [] this is what I get